# Allow users to add their own code and execute them when the conditions matches

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-s3

I am working on a Multi tenant application and have to allow users to add their own code and run them when the condition matches.

I got few ideas on mind, but don't know which method is best.

*All the methods listed below will be able to differentiate between the code added by different users and the tenant they belong to.*

**Method #1:**
Store the user added code in files, and when the condition matches, just load that file, execute the code. Simple and it will work.

But depending on the no. of users using the app and the amount of custom code they add, this is not a highly Scalable solution.

**Method #2:**
Same as `Method #1` but here we store the code in **S3 bucket** and load it directly from S3 when we have to execute it.

This way i don't have worry about file system or anything and this is a Scalable solution.

**Method #3:**
Database, Store the code in database, validate it before storing and when its time to execute the code, Just load it from database and execute it.

Simple, scalable and best (if done right).

Although `Method #3` is my favorite, I think `Method #2` will be the best solution here as later i can allow users to upload their code instead of using our platform to write it.

Do you guys have any other recommendations? Have any experience in implementing this? where could this go wrong*?

Comment: Method #2 seems to be best for this one...

Comment: Allowing users to "write their own code," particularly in a multi-tenant environment, sounds like a recipe for trouble.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yup, but that's what the universe is moving towards.

Comment: I guess that depends on what you mean.  Of course, custom *logic* != exposed/contributed/editable custom *code*.  Custom code across an arms-length, well-defined interface is one thing.  Custom code that's inlined or "eval'ed" in a more privileged context is another entirely, and... *shudder*.  #3 - database - seems the obvious choice, but I believe this question is too broad or opinion based to be a good candidate, here.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot True, I was thinking of running the code in its own process so even when it fails, the app will continue functioning., And it is opinion based, That's the reason i asked.. thinking someone who might have already done this can share their experience., I haven't done this and hence have no experience in this field.. But i will play around with all the methods and stick with what works for me.

Answer (score 0):

method 3 would be best, from what it sounds like. Use a variant of SQL to create the database, and keep a method of SQL querying. In my experience with databases, if you keep your table well organized, it would be a better platform than the other methods, and you could use some unholy hybrid of javascript to create a new tenant in your database with SQL.